# Issues with a universal brick game, grid works on ipad but not iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Im stuck with an issue that I cannot solve.

I´ve created a brick game (41 bricks and 1 empty square) on a grid that is 6x7.  The code below shows how I created the grid and the picture called “correct” shows how the bricks should be placed on the grid.

[image]
(init file, adding the bricks)

```
            CCSpriteBatchNode *SpriteBatchNode;

            [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]

             addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"bricks_iPad.plist"];
            SpriteBatchNode =

            [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"bricks_iPad.png"];
            [self addChild:SpriteBatchNode z:1 tag:kSSheet];

            for(int i =0; i< GRID_WIDTH ; i++) {
                for(int j =0; j< GRID_HEIGHT ; j++) {
                    Bricks * b = [[Bricks alloc]initWithGame:self];
                    grid[i][j] = b; 

                    [b release];
                }
            }
```

(place the bricks)

```
int BlankX = blankPosition.x;
int BlankY = blankPosition.y;

CCLOG(@"BlankX %d", BlankX);
CCLOG(@"BlankY %d", BlankY);

//empty spot in the bottom right corner of the grid
switch (level){
    case 1:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(5, 0);          
        break;
    case 10: 
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;
    case 20:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;  
    case 30:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;
    case 40:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;
    case 50:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;  
    case 60:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;
    case 70:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);            
        break;
    case 80:
        blankPosition = CGPointMake(BlankX, BlankY);        
        break;
}

       for(int i =0; i< GRID_WIDTH ; i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j< GRID_HEIGHT ; j++)
            {

                CGPoint orgPosition = CGPointMake(i,j);

                if( blankPosition.x == orgPosition.x && blankPosition.y == orgPosition.y ){

                    Bricks * d = grid[i][j];
                    d.bricksType = 25; //give the blank location a unique value to prevent it to be matched with the rest of the bricks
                    continue;
                }

                Bricks * leftB = nil;
                Bricks *leftmostB= nil;
                Bricks * topB= nil;
                Bricks *topmostB= nil;
                int prohibitedLeft = -1, prohibitedTop = -1;
                if(i>=2)
                {
                    leftB = (Bricks *)grid[i-1][j];
                    leftmostB = (Bricks *)grid[i-2][j];
                }
                if(j>=2)
                {
                    topB = (Bricks *)grid[i][j-1];
                    topmostB = (Bricks *)grid[i][j-2];
                }
                if(leftB && leftmostB && leftB.bricksType == leftmostB.bricksType)
                {
                    prohibitedLeft = leftB.bricksType;
                }
                if(topB && topmostB && topB.bricksType == topmostB.bricksType)
                {
                    prohibitedTop = topB.bricksType;
                }
                [grid[i][j] placeInGrid:ccp(100*i + GRID_OFFSETIPHONE.x,101*j + GRID_OFFSETIPHONE.y) pt:prohibitedTop pl:prohibitedLeft amount:AmountOfBricks];

            }
        }
```

Everything works fine when I try it on the iPad simulator but when I try the same code on the iPhone simulator the bricks end up in a similar way as the picture “wrong” shows. I. e. all over the place.
I´ve tried with several values(the space between the bricks) and several sizes on the bricks but nothing works. (The size of the bricks that work for the ipad is 100x103 and the values 100*I and 101*j).

[image]

What am I missing?

Q: Is there a way that I can (and I know that this might sound weird), highlight the squares (without the bricks) on the grid to be able to find out the correct size that I should use for the bricks.

NOTE: One thing that I noticed (but I don´t know if it´s relevant) when I remove the values infront of i and j on the ipad code is that the bricks line up on top each other on the left bottom side of the grid, only showing one brick, the brick on top.  BUT when I do the same thing to the bricks in the iPhone code, they line up 2 bricks next to each other and the rest underneath them and sometimes 4 bricks (2 on top and 2 on the bottom, making a bigger square). 
Why is that? Can this cause this issue that I am experiencing?

Comment: Have you run it with a debugger and looked at what is happening line by line? I'd suggest adding just a few bricks to start tracking things down.

Comment: tried that... can´t find anything wrong with the code. I am currently trying with 4 bricks for the iphone code but the issue persists. tried with 1, 2 and 3 as well

Comment: started to wonder if the issue is in the .plist. I tried to use the .plist for the ipad in the iphone code, but the sprites never appeared. the sprites appeared on the ipad simulator, when I tried the plist from the iphone part on the ipad part

Comment: Can you please post the snapshot of your device which display empty brick.

Comment: not enough reputation to post pictures...:(

Comment: @V.J. Maybe I can e-mail them to you?

Comment: Now you can post images. its 11. :)

Comment: @V.J. nice :), the pictures will show how it should be (the empty square is at the bottom right corner) and how it should´t (the bricks are all over the place). let me know if the pictures aren´t good :)

Comment: Comment below if condition and try again.
if( blankPosition.x == orgPosition.x && blankPosition.y == orgPosition.y ){
R u able to share your code. So i can run it in my system.?

Comment: I can only share a part of the code... the bricks part. will that help?

Comment: I commented the if condition but it ended up the same way.

Comment: @V.J How much of the code do you need? I can share the bricks files and some parts of the game scene.